# Why xmlrpc wordpress do not work in some live site but in some it is working.

Tags: wordpress, hook, xml-rpc

I am trying to post to site 2 (demo.com) from site 1 (test.com) using code below.  it is not working.

But when i try to post from localhost to site 1(demo.com) with same code it works. 
I do not know what is the problem. Please help me. Thank you

```
   $client = new IXR_Client("http://demo.com/xmlrpc.php");
   $postcontent = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_title' => 'wwww',
                'post_name' => 'wwww',
                'post_content' => 'wwww'

            );

   $res = $client -> query('wp.newPost',1, "username", "password", $postcontent);
   $postID =  $client->getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the wordpress server you are trying to post to has IP based whitelisting or blacklisting enabled.

`.htaccess` file on the server would have the rules for the same.

The server has to allow xmlrpc.php file for your client.